# Autocomplete: change color on hover and on pressing up and down keys

Tags: jquery-ui

Documentation and example:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I fail to made the suggested variants to change color on hover and moving up and down in list by arrows. So, my suggested variants are alwais colorless no matter whether I hover the mouse over variants or press up or down.

Could you give me a kick here? I mean what class is responsible for that. Or where in in the example in the documentation it is organized (styles or something).

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The Demos on the site work just fine, so we need to see what is different about your current code and why it is not working.

Comment: Also it uses `ui-state-highlight` See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/